# Copy file from Folder on windows phone to Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am struggling with a problem concerning copying files to an isolated storage.

At this moment i can copy a file from my project folder to an isolated storage.

```
 IsolatedStorageFile isostore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            isostore.DeleteFile("Cabines.sdf");
            if (!isostore.FileExists("Cabines.sdf"))
            {
                //Open stream
                using (Stream DbIn = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("CabineManager/Cabines.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                {

                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream DbOut = isostore.CreateFile("Cabines.sdf"))
                    {
                        byte[] readBuffer = new Byte[4096]; //Default buffer size
                        int bytesRead = -1;
                        while ((bytesRead = DbIn.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            DbOut.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }

                }
                isostore.Dispose();
```

I would like to copy the file from the {PhoneDirectory}\CabineManager\Cabines.sdf to the isolated storage. But this is not as easy as i thought. I already spend a few hours without finding a clear solution for this problem.

I already tried some stuff with StorageFolder but i can't seem to find a solution. Is it impossible to acces these folders? (with windows you never know)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 8: The right way to Read & Write Files in WinRT](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)  details all the different kinds of file access you need to do in a store app.

You're trying to do this without the file picker? Have you changed your appxmanifest?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

I already tried with a filepicker and i followed the instructions on the website you gave me. But again i get the exception that the methods aren't implemented. I get this with storagefolder method too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not implemented Its a not supported exception.